# How to clone a child class instance within a parent class method

Tags: php, phpstorm, clone, extends

I have a child class. My parent class has an instance method that clones `$this` and fluently returns the clone. I want to use that instance method with my child class instance, but I get hints in my IDE (PhpStorm) that the returned value is an instance of the parent class, not of the child class as I would have expected:

```php
<?php
class myParentClass
{
    public function doAThing()
    {
        $clone = clone $this;
        // ... doing things
        return $clone;
    }
}

class myChildClass extends myParentClass {
    public function doTricks()
    {
        // ... do some tricks
    }
}

$myChild = new myChildClass();
$myChild = $myChild->doAThing(); // returns myParentClass instance, not myChildClass
$myChild->doTricks(); // Error, myParentClass doesn't have a doTricks() method
```

How can I get `myChildClass::doAThing()` to pass back a `myChildClass` instance?

Comment: What's your php version, everything seems correct https://3v4l.org/HhjnA

Comment: Using v7.4. My IDE just gripes at me for using the wrong return type, so it won't provide hinting for my child class instances. Tried all sorts of PHPDoc hints and declaring `:self` return types, but to no avail.

Comment: Which IDE you are using? Please add this to your question.

Comment: @greeflas PHPStorm. Added to question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add following PHPDoc block and PhpStorm will known what object actually returned

```
class myParentClass
{
    /**
     * @return static
     */
    public function doAThing()
    {
        $clone = clone $this;
        // ... doing things
        return $clone;
    }
}
```

Comment: And in php8 you can `public function doAThing(): static`)

Comment: Oh god, it's always the most obvious thing once you see it. Leaving the question since I couldn't find any references to this anywhere. Knowing how to use PHPDoc fixes so much s***.

Comment: @u_mulder yes, thank you for the reminder. Slowly moving projects to php8. Most of mine are still <7.3.

Comment: It's a good question, but your title doesn't reflect what you actually wanted to know.  A better title would have been:  "Child class that calls parent method to return clone shows as parent class instance in PHPStorm."  Even better would be to include the exact messaging you got from PHPStorm, because in the future, people will cut and paste the message into Google.